# why changing the tensor object to tf.constant works

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I have two code, which is doing the same thing but having different output.

This is the first code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
input_tf = tf.Variable([ [9.968594,  8.655439,  0.,        0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.3356,    0.,        8.8974   ],
                         [0.,        0.,        6.103182,  7.330564 ],
                         [6.609862,  0.,        3.0614321, 0.       ],
                         [9.497023,  0.,        3.8914037, 0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.457685,  8.602337,  0.       ],
                         [0.,        0.,        5.826657,  8.283971 ],
                         [0.,        0.,        0.,        0.       ]])
rows_tf = tf.constant (
[[1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 4, 7]])
columns_tf = tf.constant(
[[1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2],
 [3],
 [2]])
rows_tf = tf.reshape(rows_tf, shape=[-1, 1])
print(rows_tf.shape)
columns_tf = tf.reshape(
    tf.tile(columns_tf, multiples=[1, 3]),
    shape=[-1, 1])
print(columns_tf.shape)
sparse_indices = tf.reshape(
    tf.concat([rows_tf, columns_tf], axis=-1),
    shape=[-1, 2])
print(sparse_indices.shape)
v = tf.gather_nd(input_tf, sparse_indices)
v = tf.reshape(v, [-1, 3])

print(rows_tf.shape) (8,3)
print(columns_tf.shape) (8,1)
print(rows_tf.shape) (24,1)
print(columns_tf.shape) (24,1)
```

Which giving me the desired output:

```
[[8.3356    0.        8.457685 ]
 [0.        6.103182  8.602337 ]
 [8.8974    7.330564  0.       ]
 [0.        3.8914037 5.826657 ]
 [8.8974    0.        8.283971 ]
 [6.103182  3.0614321 5.826657 ]
 [7.330564  0.        8.283971 ]
 [6.103182  3.8914037 0.       ]], shape=(8, 3), dtype=float32)
```

I have another code which is a process for calculating 'rows_tf' and 'columns_tf'.
so, `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` are not constant but the result of other calculations(their shape and value are the same).

this is my second part of the code which not giving the exact above code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
n = 2
tf_a1 = tf.Variable([    [9.968594,  8.655439,  0.,        0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.3356,    0.,        8.8974   ],
                         [0.,        0.,        6.103182,  7.330564 ],
                         [6.609862,  0.,        3.0614321, 0.       ],
                         [9.497023,  0.,        3.8914037, 0.       ],
                         [0.,        8.457685,  8.602337,  0.       ],
                         [0.,        0.,        5.826657,  8.283971 ]])

tf_a2 = tf.constant([[2, 5, 1],
                     [1, 6, 4],
                     [0, 0, 0],
                     [2, 3, 6],
                     [4, 2, 4]])
N, M = tf_a1.shape
input_tf = tf.concat([tf_a1, tf.zeros((1, tf_a1.shape[1]), tf_a1.dtype)], axis=0)

tf_a2 = tf.sort(tf_a2, axis=1)
first_col_change = tf.zeros([tf_a2.shape[0], 1], dtype=tf.int32)
last_cols_change = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf_a2[:, 1:], tf_a2[:, :-1]), tf.int32)
change_bool = tf.concat([first_col_change, last_cols_change], axis=-1)
not_change_bool = 1 - change_bool
tf_a2_changed = tf_a2 * not_change_bool + change_bool * N

# y,x = tf.where(tf.count_nonzero(a1p[a2], axis=1) >= n)
idx = tf.where(tf.count_nonzero(tf.gather(input_tf, tf_a2_changed, axis=0), axis=1) >= n)
x, y = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]

rows_tf = tf.gather(tf_a2, y, axis=0)
columns_tf = tf.cast(x[:, None],tf.int32)

out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(input_tf, dtype=tf.int32))

rows_tf = tf.reshape(rows_tf, shape=[-1, 1])

columns_tf = tf.reshape(
    tf.tile(columns_tf, multiples=[1, 3]),
    shape=[-1, 1])
sparse_indices = tf.reshape(
    tf.concat([rows_tf, columns_tf], axis=-1),
    shape=[-1, 2])

v = tf.gather_nd(input_tf, sparse_indices)
v = tf.reshape(v, [-1, 3])
print(v)


  print(rows_tf.shape) (8,3)
  print(columns_tf.shape) (8,1)
  print(rows_tf.shape) (24,1)
  print(columns_tf.shape) (24,1)
```

In this code the

```
rows_tf = tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 5]
 [1 2 5]
 [1 2 5]
 [1 4 6]
 [1 4 6]
 [2 3 6]
 [2 3 6]
 [2 4 4]], shape=(8, 3), dtype=int32)
```

and

```
columns_tf= tf.Tensor(
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [2]
 [3]
 [2]
 [3]
 [2]], shape=(8, 1), dtype=int32)
```

So, I mean in the first code the only thing I have done is that I create a constant tensor of these, rather than including the code to produce these tensors. why their result is different then?

and this is the output of this code:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.       9.497023 0.      ]
 [9.968594 9.968594 9.968594]
 [0.       6.609862 0.      ]
 [8.655439 8.655439 8.655439]
 [0.       0.       0.      ]
 [0.       0.       0.      ]
 [7.330564 0.       8.283971]
 [0.       0.       0.      ]], shape=(8, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Why this is happening at all? if you change the `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` to `constant tensor` of the first code it will give the correct result!(I should also mention that `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` in the second code are exactly the ones in the first code). in the first code just to make it reproducible I define the tensor as the constant tensor.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you print out `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` to check that they are actually the same at the ones in the first snippet? Because when I tried, they weren't the same.

Comment: @ImperishableNight Thanks for following up. yes they are exactly the same, we have two `rows_tf` and `columns_tf`. the first `rows_tf` is (8,3) which is the same as the constant and also `columns_tf' ia (8,1). please pay attention that you should print out the first rows_tf and columns_tf as they are the same as the constant on the first snippet. both snippet has the second one.

Comment: I can only get them to be the same by changing `x, y = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]` to `y, x = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]`. Typo in question?

Comment: And when I change `x, y` to `y, x`, I get the correct output (same output as from the first snippet).

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question with some information about the second code. and the shape of rows_tf and columns_tf. So the correct snippet is in the question and `x` and `y` should not change, and the purpose of the question is that what is the conflict here.

Comment: That's strange. When I run the second code, `rows_tf` and `columns_tf` (the first ones) still aren't the same. Furthermore, I don't even get an answer, and get an error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[23] = [0, 4] does not index into param shape [8,4] [Op:GatherNd]` instead. What are the values of `x` and `y` on your side?

Comment: Thats weird, which version f tensorflow are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195161/discussion-between-imperishable-night-and-sariii).

Comment: @ImperishableNight Actually, you were right. yesterday I was too tired :|, I had written the whole thing I want in numpy, then I wanted to convert to tf which this confusion came:|. please add your answer so I will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second snippet in the question was wrong, and it didn't give the same values for `rows_tf` and `columns_tf`. The problem was this line:

```
x, y = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]
```

It should be:

```
y, x = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]
```

After making this correction, the snippet gives the correct values for `rows_tf` and `columns_tf`, and also the correct final answer.